# Uncaught ReferenceError : angular is not defined (Using testem)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs

Error is found in line 1 of 2 files: 
- controllers.js 
- app.js

Which is attached below together with html.

The app appears when I start up local server but I am unable to login or signup by clicking the sign up button after entering my details. Is it a 404 error?

I also tried to add these 2 lines into the index.html file (I thought was some items I didnt define) but did not work.

**index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    *<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->*
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script> <!-- firebase -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js"></script> <!-- angularfire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js"></script> <!-- firebase-simple-login -->

    *<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->*
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body ng-app="bucketList" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-chevron-left">
        Back
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

**controllers.js file** (Error in first line)

```
angular.module('bucketList.controllers', [])
    .controller('SignInCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseAuth', '$window',
```

**app.js file (Error in first line)**

```
angular.module('bucketList', ['ionic', 'firebase', 'bucketList.controllers'])
```

Answer (score 8):

The error says, you are attempt to use `angular` before load the script. I didn't see any reference of `angularjs` library in your `index.html` file.

So add a reference for `angularjs` before `app.js` and `controller.js`.

Comment: To add angular in the form of <script src="js/app.js"></script>? 
Could you write an example? 

I tried 
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>

and <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

and <scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>

It gave more 404 errors...

Comment: <script src="js/angularjs.js"></script>

AND 

<script src="js/angular.js"></script>

didnt work either. 
Do i have to do any bundle install or anything like that?

Comment: Do you have `angularjs` in your `js` directory ? otherwise you can reference from `CDN` like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.14/angular.min.js"></script>` then add your local script like `<script src="js/app.js"></script> <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry Im very new to angular JS...how do i add the google's ref? or create new js file? I added the ajax script u list above but my local server app totally blanked out.

Comment: you do not need the angular script file .as it is already included in the ionic bundle file

Comment: Including <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"> didnt work

Answer (score 1):

App.js

```
      angular.module('bucketList', ['ionic', 'firebase'])
         .run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth, $firebase, $window, $ionicLoading) {
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
             if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
```

controller.js

```
          angular.module('bucketList', [])
           .controller('SignInCtrl', [
                      '$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseAuth', '$window',
                       function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth, $window) {
                       $rootScope.checkSession();

                         $scope.user = {
                                  email: "",
                                    password: ""
```

Comment: didnt work. removing bucketList.controllers completely disabled the button functions.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The original issue was 
Uncaught ReferenceError : angular is not defined.

If I change it based on your edits, the entire screen disappears.

Comment: and do move the app.js script tag below the controllers.js

Comment: When I change it based on your edits. 
Screen is blank and this is the error.

>Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8100/cordova.js
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bucketList due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bucketList.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'bucketList.controllers' is not available! ...<omitted>...1) ionic.bundle.js:12837

Comment: bucketList.controllers remove it from from the app.js   angular.module('bucketList', ['ionic', 'firebase'])